# Repeat the value in column B until there is a change in column A

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by, cumsum

I need the value repeated in column B until a change occur in column A.

Here's the Input

```
    Column A  Column B
     18         1
     18         0
     18         0
     18         0
     24         2
     24         0
     18         3
     18         0
     18         0
     18         0
```

Expected output

```
   Column A  Column B
    18         1
    18         1
    18         1
    18         1
    24         2
    24         2
    18         3
    18         3
    18         3
    18         3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by `first` if need repeat first value of each group by `Series` which is create by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of shifted column `Col A`:

```
print (df['Col A'].ne(df['Col A'].shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
8    3
9    3
Name: Col A, dtype: int32

df['Col B'] = df.groupby(df['Col A'].ne(df['Col A'].shift()).cumsum())['Col B']
                .transform('first')
print (df)
   Col A  Col B
0     18      1
1     18      1
2     18      1
3     18      1
4     24      2
5     24      2
6     18      3
7     18      3
8     18      3
9     18      3
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain how the 'first' is working here. Because the above code is not working in Ipython Notebook and Azure Ml

Comment: error: 

File ".\Script Bundle\co.py", line 141, in pipeline_1
    df['Last_Act_User'] = df.groupby(df['thermostat'].ne(df['thermostat'].shift()).cumsum())['Last_Act_User'].transform('first')
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2210, in transform
    res = wrapper(group)
  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2203, in <lambda>
    wrapper = lambda x: getattr(x, func)(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: first() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Yes, I see your question, but in Azure I never work :(

Comment: It is not working on Jupyter Notebook as well. I'm guessing, its something to do with version.

Comment: Is possible upgrade? last version is `0.19.2`

Comment: this is the version i'm working on:

Microsoft Drawbridge Console Host [Version 1.0.2108.0] Running with Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: and version of pandas?

Comment: I'm guessing it Version 1.0.2108.0

Comment: Can you suggest me an alternative solution to the initial problem.

Comment: If always first value by group in `column B` is no `0`, you can use `print (df['Column B'].replace({0:np.nan}).ffill())
`

Comment: By default, not all the values are 0. Hence its not giving appropriate result

Answer (score 0):

```
A =[18,18,18,18,24,24,18,18,18,18]
def func(A):
    B = []
    b = 1
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if i == 0:
            B.append(b)
            continue
        if A[i] != A[i-1]:
            b += 1
            B.append(b)          
        else:
            B.append(b)
    return B
```

out:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```